# Употребление слова "абстрагироваться"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Мне кажется, модное нынче слово "абстрагироваться" часто употребляют не к месту, а именно там, где корректно было бы писать "игнорировать", "отбросить" или "не принимать во внимание". Хотелось бы свериться с опытными участниками.

Словарь говорит об отвлечении от несущественного для того, чтобы выделить основное:

> [АБСТРАГИРОВАТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), -рую, -руешь; св. и нсв. что. Мысленно отвлекаясь от каких-л. признаков, свойств, связей предмета или явления, выделить - выделять его основные закономерные признаки, свойства и связи; рассмотреть - рассматривать что-л. в отвлечении от его несущественных сторон, признаков. А. свойства предмета. А. общие свойства двух процессов. <Абстрагироваться, -руется; страд.

Вот, на мой взгляд, примеры корректного употребления:

> 1. Трудно **абстрагироваться** от древесины, деревянного и всякой д.в.п., — надо уметь в красках и запахах представлять или наблюдать живой образец лет под тысячу, по крайней мере. (Sharon на этом сайте)
> 2. Но можно рассматривать его и со стороны содержания самой деятельности субъекта, **абстрагируясь** от других его сторон и отношений. [А. Н. Леонтьев. Биологическое и социальное в психике человека (1981)]
> 3. Модель программирования определяет основные идеи и стиль программной реализации, **абстрагируясь** от алгоритмического языка и, частично, от hardware. [Владимир Карпов, Алексей Лобанов. Кризисы программного жанра // «За науку», 2011]
> 4. Если вы чувствуете чужую боль как свою, если вас мутит от одного запаха крови, если, вы не можете резать по живому и **абстрагироваться** от чужой боли, вам не место среди эскулапов. [Чингиз Абдуллаев. Мистерия эпохи заката (2007)]
> 5. Получается, что для объяснения действительности адекватно самой действительности нам необходимо **абстрагироваться** от особенностей нашего мышления. [Борис Соколов. Число и мышление, наука и фольклор // «Знание - сила», 2006]

А вот примеры спорные. Общее для многих из них: есть несколько равнозначных факторов и мы "абстрагируемся" от одного из них. Корректно ли это? Напомню, абстрагирование — это отвлечении от несущественного для того, чтобы выделить основное.

> 1. Безусловно, один из факторов дороговизны российских инвестиций ― необходимость приобретения и установки импортных машин и оборудования, рублевые цены на которые объективно весьма высоки. Однако нельзя **абстрагироваться** и от других факторов. [Андрей Косарев. Эсперанто международных сравнений // «Эксперт», 2014]
> 2. Причем авторов такого решения абсолютно не беспокоили его неизбежные последствия не только для Сербии, но и для других стран. Главные ― что это подталкивает во всем мире сепаратизм. Предоставление независимости Косову может привести к нежелательным изменениям политической карты на Балканах. Нет никаких оснований **абстрагироваться** от многолетних планов создания «Великой Албании», а может быть, теперь и «Великого Косова», к которому будут тяготеть Санджак, мусульманские части Македонии, Черногории. Настораживают также прорывающиеся наружу планы ликвидировать Республику Сербскую в Боснии и Герцеговине (БиГ). [Е. М. Примаков. Мир без России? К чему ведет политическая близорукость (2009)]
> 3. Остерегаясь ловушки, он не пошел в церковь, на “отчитку”, фрагмент которой показали по каналу “Культура”. Все-таки навеки расстаться со своим даром он тоже не решался. Но он искал других “чудес” ― положения, успеха, достатка. Научился **абстрагироваться** от страшной ноши, жить гладко, точно, на автомате, не допуская волшебных осечек. [Сергей Шаргунов. Чародей (2008) // , ]

В этом примере оказывается, что насекомые способны к абстрактному мышлению (?!):

> 4. Переносчик пыльцы действует, как будто зная, что измерять можно только с помощью жестких стержней, не меняющих существенно свою длину в тех границах температурных колебаний, тех изменений давления, влажности, электромагнитных флуктуаций, в которых возможна жизнь. От химического строения измерительного прибора насекомое **абстрагируется**.

В этом примере сказано, что для того, чтобы изучать граффити, нужно абстрагироваться от любования закорючками и цветовыми извивами. Но ведь любование закорючками — вообще не признак и не свойство граффити. Каша какая-то:

> 5. Да и те, кто занимается граффити, исходя из своих принципов и своеобразия собственного творчества, не стремятся выходить из тени, где спокойнее и приемлемее им находиться. Любая попытка формализации чего бы то ни было в этой деятельности ― за пределами интересов авторов граффити, поскольку они по сути своего творчества хотят быть как будто бы вне общества. Необходим значительный кураж, чтобы не только быть в граффити самим собой, но и изучать граффити с разных точек зрения. Нужна дистанция, умение **абстрагироваться** от любования этими закорючками и цветовыми извивами и независимость от предубеждения и наукообразия при наличии любви к тому, что захочется изучать. [Илья Абель. Новый палимпсест или краткий словарь иностранных слов // «Знание - сила», 2005]

Answer (score 1):

Мне представляется неестественным приводить в *толковом* словаре сначала *переходный* глагол "**абстрагировать**" и затем как грамматическую форму выводить из него *возвратный* глагол "**абстрагироваться**", который используется гораздо чаще (85:17 по статистике "корпуса"); при этом приводится общее определение (?!).  Первый глагол уместен в контекстах растолкования чего-либо другим, второй - когда говорится о способе (или частном приёме) собственного мышления.

Из пяти положительных примеров с глаголом "абстрагироваться" в тексте вопроса мне видятся безупречными только второй и четвёртый. В третьем и пятом предлагают абстрагироваться от абстрактного (от машинного языка и особенностей собственного мышления). Последующие примеры "спорных" и явно ошибочных случаев употребления говорят о последствиях отмены языкового контроля на телевидении и в других влиятельных СМИ.

Answer (score 1):

**Абстрагироваться** ― это довольно популярный в настоящее время глагол, и его не всегда удобно заменять словами ***игнорировать, отбросить, не принимать во внимание, не касаться***, хотя все эти слова  можно считать **близкими синонимами.**

**И значение у этого глагола вполне понятное.**

В каждой конкретной ситуации мы можем выделить **существенные для нас стороны**, отвлекаясь от других и не принимая их во внимание. Это совершенно нормально, по большому счету так строится сам процесс познания. Но и рассуждая о вещах обычных,  мы всегда стремимся **обозначить нечто определенное**, обратить на это внимание собеседника.

Возможно, **область применения глагола расширяется, но ничего ошибочного в этом я не нахожу.**

**[АБСТРАГИРОВАТЬСЯ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F),**  св. и нсв. от чего. Мысленно **отвлечься - отвлекаться** от тех или иных признаков, свойств и связей предметов и явлений с целью выделения **существенных и закономерных** признаков. **А. от чувственных ощущений.**

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ссылку на словарь.

Comment: Все-таки для "выделения существенных и закономерных признаков", а не отбрасывание призвольно того или иного признака, тем более не признака ("чтобы изучать граффити, нужно абстрагироваться от любования закорючками и цветовыми извивами" (?!)

Comment: Я думаю, что существенность и закономерность для каждого случая  определяет автор высказывания. В одной ситуации одно существенно, в другой - другое (для него, для автора).

Comment: А словарь Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру.

Comment: А мне порой кажется, что автор не к абстракции стремится, а просто словами играет.

Comment: Этот глагол расширил свое значение и область применения, поэтому это уже не стремление к научной абстракции, а просто отвлечение от признаков, которые в текущий момент не рассматриваются.

Comment: Придется признать, что так. А жаль. Есть ведь хорошие варианты: то же "отвлечься от" (которое Вы упомянули), не рассматривать, не принимать во внимание, не касаться и т. д. Все от желания  выразиться позаковыристей!

Comment: Мне кажется, что наоборот, то есть выразиться короче, понятнее и особенно не напрягаясь при выборе слов. Вот пример: Однако президент произнес короткую программную речь, стремясь успокоить инвесторов и абстрагироваться от политической повестки дня. [Дмитрий Яковенко. Где низкие ставки? // «Эксперт», 2014]  Кажется, что здесь глагол не совсем уместен, а чем его заменить, как сказать по-другому.?

Comment: Я этот пример видел, но не привел как ошибочный, так как я согласен со сказанным: президент действительно рассуждал несколько абстрактно. Возможно, автор и не хотел этого сказать, но сказал.